Retrive PDF sendcloud
I'm trying to get a PDF through a request
      await admin.firestore().collection("negocios").doc(data.uid_empresa).collection("Sendcloud").doc("info").get().then(async (cloud:any) => {
        var sendcloud = cloud.data();
        const bearerToken = Buffer.from(sendcloud.publica + ":" + sendcloud.privada).toString('base64')
        const options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: "https://panel.sendcloud.sc/api/v2/labels/normal_printer/" + data.parcel_id,
          params: {start_from: '0'},
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/pdf, application/json',
            Authorization: 'Basic ' + bearerToken
          }
        };

        try {
          const { data } = await axios.request(options);
          res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data));

        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(400).send(error);
        }
      });

"res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data))" returns me a pdf in this format:
%PDF-1.3 %���� 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R /PageMode /UseThumbs>>endobj2obj<</Type /Pages/Kids [ 4 0 R ]/Count 1
In typescript I download the pdf:

            this._denda.GetEtiqueta(datos).then(async (etiqueta:any) => {            
              var downloadLink      = document.createElement('a');
              downloadLink.target   = '_blank';
              downloadLink.download = 'name_to_give_saved_file.pdf';
            
              // convert downloaded data to a Blob
              var blob = new Blob([etiqueta], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            
              // create an object URL from the Blob
              var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
              var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            
              // set object URL as the anchor's href
              downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
            
              // append the anchor to document body
              document.body.append(downloadLink);
            
              // fire a click event on the anchor
              downloadLink.click();
            
              // cleanup: remove element and revoke object URL
              document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
              URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);

            });

But when I open the pdf it does not show me the information or the barcodes correctly, and I also get the error "cannot extract embedded font..."

Following the Sendcloud documentation I don't see anything strange and the pdf that is automatically sent to the email looks correct.
Has this happened to anyone?
thank you
